# Change specific lines using sed

Tags: sed

I have a html file and i want to edit from 8th line till next to the last line i.e no changes to 1-7 and the last line with sed utility.

Example:

```
line 1 <i>some text<i>
line 2 <i>some text<i>
line 3 <i>some text<i>
line 4 <i>some text<i>
line 5 <i>some text<i>
line 6 <i>some text<i>
line 7 <i>some text<i>
line 8 <i>some text<i>
line 9 <i>some text<i>
line 10 <i>some text<i>
S       <i>some text<i>
o       <i>some text<i>
-       <i>some text<i>
o       <i>some text<i>
n       <i>some text<i>   
line N <i>some text<i>
```

To

```
line 1 <i>some text<i>
line 2 <i>some text<i>
line 3 <i>some text<i>
line 4 <i>some text<i>
line 5 <i>some text<i>
line 6 <i>some text<i>
line 7 <i>some text<i>
line 8 some text
line 9 some text
line 10 some text
S       some text
o       some text
-       some text
o       some text
n       some text   
line N <i>some text<i>
```

How can i?
Thanks in advance for suggestions and help .
Regards

Comment: http://tille.garrels.be/training/sed.php  <> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-last-n-lines-of-a-file <> http://askubuntu.com/questions/290082/change-specific-lines-using-sed

Comment: Not really helpful, See there are two range as i don't know the number of last line. (8,$|$!) but i don't think it will work. Any workaround will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your limit is up to and including next-to-last line, you can get away with using `$!` as a condition for the substitution:

```
sed '8,$ { $! s:</\?i>::g }' infile
```